# The survexp function from the survival package ends with an error

Tags: r, survival-analysis

I use survexp with two data sets. The study group (mgus dataset from the survival package) and the rate table (survexp.us also from the survival package).

Unfortunately, the function call ends with an error:

```
> library("survival")

> mgus2=mgus

> mgus2$dxyr =  as.character(mgus2$dxyr+1900)

> head(mgus2)
  id age    sex dxyr pcdx pctime futime death alb creat  hgb mspike
1  1  78 female 1968 <NA>     NA    748     1 2.8   1.2 11.5    2.0
2  2  73 female 1966   LP   1310   6751     1  NA    NA   NA    1.3
3  3  87   male 1968 <NA>     NA    277     1 2.2   1.1 11.2    1.3
4  4  86   male 1969 <NA>     NA   1815     1 2.8   1.3 15.3    1.8
5  5  74 female 1968 <NA>     NA   2587     1 3.0   0.8  9.8    1.4
6  6  81   male 1968 <NA>     NA    563     1 2.9   0.9 11.5    1.8
> 

        > fite <- survexp(Surv(futime, death) ~ 1, data=mgus2, ratetable=survexp.us, 
        +                 rmap=list(age=age*365.25, sex=c("female", "male"), year=dxyr))


    Error in (function (..., row.names = NULL, check.rows = FALSE, check.names = TRUE,  : 
          arguments imply differing number of rows: 241, 2
```

Is it necessary to e.g. prepare the dataset mgus in some way in order to use it with the function survexp as above?

Answer (score 0):

The error arises because of the redefinition of the sex variable when including this in the 'rmap' list:  `sex=c("female", "male"),`

Once you remove that apparently unnecessary redefinition, you then get a a very informative further error:

```
 fite <- survexp(Surv(futime, death) ~ 1, data=mgus2, ratetable=survexp.us, rmap=list( year=dxyr))
Error in match.ratetable(rdata, ratetable) : 
  for this ratetable, year must be a continuous variable
```

You can leave the redefinition of the age variable (which was left out above) but it only succeeds with `year` (or rather `dxyr`) being numeric:

```
mgus2$dxyr =  mgus2$dxyr+1900
fite <- survexp(Surv(futime, death) ~ 1, data=mgus2, 
                 ratetable=survexp.us, rmap=list(age=age*365.25, year=dxyr))

> str(fite)
List of 6
 $ call  : language survexp(formula = Surv(futime, death) ~ 1, data = mgus2, rmap = list(age = age * 365.25, year = dxyr),      ratet| __truncated__
 $ surv  : num [1:237] 0.999 0.999 0.997 0.997 0.996 ...
 $ n.risk: int [1:237] 241 240 239 238 237 236 235 233 232 231 ...
 $ time  : num [1:237] 6 7 31 32 39 60 61 152 153 174 ...
 $ summ  : chr "  age ranges from 34 to 90 years\n  male: 137  female: 104 \n  date of entry from 1975-05-11 to 1975-05-28 \n"
 $ method: chr "cohort"
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "survexp" "survfit"

summary(fite, times=(0:30)*365.24)
Call: survexp(formula = Surv(futime, death) ~ 1, data = mgus2, rmap = list(age = age * 
    365.25, year = dxyr), ratetable = survexp.us)

  time n.risk survival
     0    241    1.000
   365    227    0.967
   730    218    0.941
  1096    210    0.904
  1461    205    0.873
  1826    193    0.841
  2191    187    0.815
  2557    176    0.787
  2922    168    0.754
  3287    155    0.730
  3652    149    0.706
  4018    143    0.677
  4383    134    0.649
  4748    129    0.624
  5113    117    0.601
  5479    105    0.583
  5844    100    0.558
  6209     87    0.536
  6574     82    0.518
  6940     73    0.497
  7305     69    0.481
  7670     67    0.464
  8035     63    0.443
  8401     58    0.427
  8766     53    0.410
  9131     44    0.391
  9496     40    0.378
  9861     35    0.360
 10227     32    0.345
 10592     30    0.331
 10957     28    0.316
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your help. I was mistakenly suggested by an example from ?survexp and gave both genders instead of one example.

```
Examples

# 
# Stanford heart transplant data
#  We don't have sex in the data set, but know it to be nearly all males.
# Estimate of conditional survival  
fit1 <- survexp(futime ~ 1, rmap=list(sex="male", year=accept.dt,   
          age=(accept.dt-birth.dt)), method='conditional', data=jasa)
...
```